# Is "ingratiate someone" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, construction

All major dictionaries provide the usage of the verb "ingratiate" as "ingratiate oneself with people". However, I just came across this line:

> Since the outset of last season, Curry has cut down on his circus shots, in part to **ingratiate Durant**. ([source](https://www.si.com/nba/2018/06/12/kevin-durant-warriors-nba-finals-champions))

With *A ingratiates Aself with B* being the common structure, I have seen a relatively uncommon, reflexive-less structure of the word: *A ingratiates A with B*, but I am hard-pressed to find any attestations of *A ingratiates B*. I haven't found any examples of this structure in Google Books. It is difficult to do an effective targeted search. Is this usage idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the word means to bring *oneself* into favour with someone through flattery or similar means.

You would therefore only use it to describe a person's *own* efforts to gain favour for themselves, for example:

> He tried to ingratiate himself with management.

It would not be correct to use "ingratiate" to mean one person's efforts on behalf of another, for example, if person A was trying to gain favour for person B from a third party. That would just be a *recommendation*.